# Convert Powershell command lines into .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, powershell, file-rename

I need to rename various files in different folders. There is a prefix 'f_' in all the filenames that need to be removed.
I managed to do this using the following lines in Powershell.

```
cd "C:\Users\pieter\Desktop\Folder1\Folder2\20140402_Export"
Get -ChildItem -filter "*f_*" -recurse | Rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace "f_","" }
```

This works, but how do I make a .bat out of this?
I would like to doubleclick a script file that automatically does the same job.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a batch file and the following there, it will execute your command in Powershell thread and exit.

```
@powershell "cd 'C:\Users\pieter\Desktop\Folder1\Folder2\20140402_Export'; Get-ChildItem -filter "*f_" -recurse | Rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace 'f_','' }"
```

Comment: I get an error: The term 'Get' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Comment: Fixed the typo (remove the space after Get), but still no results. No error either...

Comment: I managed to get it working. In your line you skipped the '*' characters.

@powershell "cd 'C:\Users\pieter\Desktop\Folder1\Folder2\20140402_Export'; Get-ChildItem -filter "*f_*" -recurse | Rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace 'f_','' }"

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@cd /d "C:\Users\pieter\Desktop\Folder1\Folder2\20140402_Export"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /s "*f_*"') do (
   set "name=%%~na"
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
      set "new=!name:f_=!"
      ren "%%a" "!new!%%~xa"
   endlocal
)
```

Comment: +1 You can omit the first `*` in `"*f_*"` and the only other issue is that it will search the short filenames too and so there could be a false match.  If you use this in the for command then it should be pretty bulletproof. `dir /b /a-d /s "f_*" ^| find /i "f_"`